# Convert string to integers

Tags: python, list, integer, sum

I'm just starting out with programming, and I know I'm still missing some of the basics, but I'm trying to work this out. I have a list of 3 and 4 digit numbers that I've brought in from a text file, and I'm trying to get a sum of these numbers. So far all I can get python to do is perform a sum of each individual number, so if the first number in the list is 427, it's printing 13, rather than adding 427 + 504 + 219, etc.

This is what I have:

```
myList = []
inFile = open('E:/GIS/GTECH 731/NYCElementarySchools.txt', 'r')
for row in inFile:
    col = row.split('\t')
    if col[1]=='BK':
        myList = (col[3])
        intList = [int(x) for x in myList]
        print sum(intList)
```

Additionally, when i have it print length, it gives me a list of 3's and 4's, telling me the length of each number, not giving me the total count of numbers.

I must be missing something fundamental, but I don't know what it is! Any suggestions are appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Please format your code by indenting it with 4 spaces.

Comment: Post some sample data from the text file.

Comment: @hcwhsa it should run fine?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan No it shouldn't, OP is iterating over a particular column's data, but they need to iterate over the list instead(or slice of a list).

Comment: @user2387370 Sorry I wanted to comment OP ...

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
myList = (col[3])
```

will set `myList` to a `str`, not a `list`, which would be a representation of a number. Thus:

```
intList = [int(x) for x in myList]
```

would convert the digits to numbers. You want `int(myList)` to convert the whole string to a number.

---

You can keep a running total (initialised to 0) and do `total += int(myList)` to total all of the numbers. Then *after* the loop you can `print` the result.

Comment: If `myList` were that, `[int(x) for x in myList]` would have thrown an error.

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
col = row.split('\t')
if col[1]=='BK':
    myList = (col[3])
    intList = [int(x) for x in myList]
    print sum(intList)
```

'col = row.split('\t')' makes a list which is divided by TAB.

If the line which is read from the file, looks like this:

```
# \t is TAB
SOMETHING\tBK\t1\t2\t3
```

The col structure is:

```
col[0] = SOMETHING
col[1] = BK
col[2] = 1
col[3] = 2
col[4] = 3
```

So, if you intend sum col[3] to col[...] then use col[3:] = list of col[3], col[4]

Thus, if you want to accumulate sum result you need another variable.

```
myList = []
inFile = open('E:/GIS/GTECH 731/NYCElementarySchools.txt', 'r')
sumList = []
for row in inFile:
    row_total = 0
    col = row.split('\t')
    if col[1]=='BK':
        intList = [int(x) for x in col[3:]]
        row_sum = sum(intList)
        # row_sum = map(lambda x: int(x), col[3:])
        print 'row total: %d' % (row_sum)
        sumList.append(row_sum)

print 'total: %d' % (sum(sumList))
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want to use a slice to assign myList

```
myList = col[3:]
```

this will return a list everything from the 3rd column on.